# LLDB type summary for a Swift object

Tags: swift, debugging, lldb

LLDB has an interesting feature called type summary which allows to change the representation of a certain type in the debugger.

Here is the documentation: https://lldb.llvm.org/varformats.html. It does not mention Swift, but according to WWDC 2014 Session 410 (Advanced Swift Debugging in LLDB, [slides](http://devstreaming.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/410xx1s19e83i5z/410/410_advanced_swift_debugging_in_lldb.pdf)) it should work for Swift objects as well.

For example, for a type `Foo`:

```
struct Foo {
  let x: Int
}
```

the LLDB command should be the following:

```
(lldb) type summary add -s "This is Foo ${var.x}" TheModuleName.Foo
```

However, this command does not seem to work. For `let foo = Foo(x: 42, y: 3.14)`. I get the following results in debugger:

```
(lldb) frame variable foo
(TheModuleName.Foo) foo = This is Foo error: summary string parsing error

(lldb) po foo
▿ Foo
  - x : 42
```

So `po` is not affected at all, and `frame variable` complains about being unable to parse the summary string.

Am I missing something? Does this feature work for Swift objects at all?

If this is relevant, I am using Swift version 3.1 with Xcode 8.3.3 (the latest stable version at the moment).

Comment: This is supposed to work.  You are probably just missing some small detail, but since your example is incomplete I can't spot what it is.  Please include a complete example and maybe we can see what is going wrong.

Comment: @JimIngham Tried reproducing this issue but couldn't. No idea why, I used the same code in the same project on the same machine. Must be one of those issues which are fixed by restarting Xcode or computer.

Comment: If you get this to fail reliably at some later date, please report it.  I can't think of any reason off the top of my head why restarting Xcode would make a correct summary provider go from fail to success.